# what is the meaning of the word "resource" in firebase firestore databse

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am developing a web app and while testing my firebase security rules i  noticed that u do not know the meaning of the word "resource", i want to be sure that the only one who can see the patitient in a Hospital should be the doctor that actually works inside the hospital

```
function iamOfThisHospital(){
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.universalIndetifier.hospital 
  == request.resource.data.universalIndetifier.hospital
}
```

Comment: What info are you looking for that isn't in this doc?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource

Comment: no, it is not. i' ve spent on it last two days

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  It's really not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: if before i wasn't enought clear, no what i am looking for is not inside the firebase doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cloud Firestore security rules, `resource` refers to the existing document in the database, and `request.resource` refers to the document as it exists in the request (during a write, i.e. a `set` or `update`).

What you probably want to for a *read* (since there is no `request.resource` on a read) is compare the user's hospital to `resource`, not `request.resource`:

```
function iamOfThisHospital(){
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.universalIndetifier.hospital 
  == resource.data.universalIndetifier.hospital
}
```